# Is it possible to address files stored in local phone storage (internal or external)?

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, addressing

I'm working on a mobile app that allows users to view media such as videos, pdfs, images, etc. The media takes a lot of space, up to 15GB. Storing the media locally within the app yields a parse error when a certain size is reached (about 4GB). I tried searching for many solutions to this issue but none has yet been successful. I am now thinking of storing the media inside the phone storage or sd card and addressing them within the app (file:///storage/emulated/0/Android...). However, this method is also not working. Please help if you know how to address local phone files in an app or if you have any other alternative solution. Thank you! (The app is Cordova based)

Comment: How do you store the media locally right now ? You may post your code.

Comment: I don't use any code for storing the media. I keep them in the app's Assets folder and use html (href) to address them (relative addressing)